# When i installed Debian grub wasn't installed

Tags: debian, boot, grub2, grub, debian-installer

While installing Debian 12 my power went out, so now I can no longer boot. Unfortunately, I do not have a USB drive and I had been installing things by placing the initrd and vmlinux onto the drive and adding it to grub. Now I am in my uefi shell and by looking at the grub directory. No efi files have been placed, is there a way to manually place the efi files? Also, there is a /boot/grub directory although there is no grub.cfg or anything else there.

Comment: What's stopping you from doing the same installation from the beginning? (serious question – what you're trying to do seems hard and error-prone, and the whole debian installation would be less work and less time. For you, as for us.)

Comment: I don't have a USB drive, and the current partition doesn't have efi files.